# Why is $f:U\to\mathbb{R}$ measurable iff $f^{-1}(a,\infty)$ is measurable for all real $a$?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Suppose $f:U\to\mathbb{R}$ is a real valued function on a measurable set $U$. The definition of measurability that I am familiar with is that $f$ is measurable iff $f^{-1}(V)$ is measurable for every open $V$ in the codomain.

Why is this equivalent to the definition that $f$ is measurable iff $f^{-1}(a,\infty)$ is measurable for every real $a$?

If $f$ is measurable, then $f^{-1}(a,\infty)$ is measurable since $(a,\infty)$ is open. For the converse, I'm only concerned with showing the preimage of an open interval is measurable. Take an open interval $(a,b)$. Since $f^{-1}(b,\infty)$ is measurable, the complement
$$
(f^{-1}(b,\infty))^c=f^{-1}(-\infty,b]$$
is also measurable. Then the intersection
$$
f^{-1}(a,\infty)\cap f^{-1}(-\infty,b]=f^{-1}(a,b]$$
is measurable.

Is there a way to continue to just show $f^{-1}(a,b)$ is measurable? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This hinges on a few facts:

- There is a countable dense subset of $\mathbb{R}$. Hence, we can find a sequence $b_n$ with limit $b$ and every $b_n < b$;  then use this to get $$(a, b) = \bigcup_{n \geq 1} (a, b_n]$$
- Every open set can be written as a countable union of segments. Hence, it suffices to only consider segments.

Answer (score 3):

*Hint:* $(a,b)=\bigcup_{n\ge1}(a,b-\frac1n]$

Comment: Hmm, that finishes it, thanks!